# automatic reply rule within Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

My plan is to add a automatic reply to all incoming emails for a exchange mailbox.  I created a rule that would check all incoming and created the template reply.  Created it so it would match a server rule so outlook would not have to be open.

If I send an email from my work account on the same exchange server, it works and sends the reply I created.  With outlook open or closed.

However, when I send email from outside the company, (my personal email), it does not get a reply.  What the heck is going on there?

I think the issue is within the selection of who the email is too.  I have tried "only to me" "where my name is in TO or CC" as well as "sent to people or distribution list".

So any ideas of why this isn't working.  I thought this question was a super user question as appose to server fault.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Possible that the server is configured not to send replies outside the company? OK to your company mail but not non-company account?